# ggplot stacked bar plots adding multiple labels on top of each column

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, stacked-chart, geom-text

I am trying to create a stacked bar chart and since some of my values are very small, instead of placing the labels inside each bar. I was wondering if I can place each values on top of the bar with the highest value and stacked below it. Then the text colour will be respective with the bar colour. I tried `y=val+1` in the `geom_text()`, however, that would add the highest value as well. Which is not what I want.

```
x<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
y1<-c(0.5,4,2,9,16)
y2<-c(.25,3,10,0.02,7)
y3<-c(2,2,16,0.023,4.5)
df1<-data.frame(x=x,v1=y1,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df2<-data.frame(x=x,v2=y2,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df3<-data.frame(x=x,v3=y3,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
pClass<-left_join(df1,df2,by="x")
pClass<-left_join(pClass,df3,by="x")
pClass<-pClass%>%pivot_longer(-x,names_to="var",values_to="val")%>%mutate(val=as.numeric(val))

ggplot(pClass,aes(x=x,y=val,fill=var))+geom_bar(position="stack",stat="identity")+
  geom_text(aes(x=x,label = prettyNum(as.numeric(val),digits = 3),y=val),size = 3,fontface="bold")
```

[image: t]

Roughly I would want something like this:  Each of the bars I will have 3 values sitting on top of the bars.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It will be tough to show some of the labels in the small categories, but this should do it:

```
ggplot(pClass,aes(x=x,y=val,fill=var, label=prettyNum(as.numeric(val),digits = 3)))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  geom_text(position="stack")
```

Or given the small intervals for your data, don't stack the bar plot:

```
ggplot(Data, aes(x = Year, y = Frequency, fill = Category)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())+
  geom_text(aes(label=Frequency), position=position_dodge(0.9), vjust=0)
```

Comment: This places all the numbers at the tip of each bar, but I have multiple values on the same timestep ("x") that are very small. Then the values would stack on top of each other. Is there a way I can place all three values on top of the bars?

Comment: I see what you mean. Why are you stacking the bars then? This will crunch your data into a smaller interval and be really difficult to visualize the small classes (labels aside). I added an alternative above to display the dodged bars.

Comment: I want to give a visual representation as a proportion of each variable of the total with stacked bars. If I use dodged bars, then it's becomes more difficult to show the total unless I add in a fourth variable representing the total of each time step